# Accidentally created a folder with a nullchar using VBA, can't delete the folder

Tags: vba, ms-access

I used MkDir on a foldername (in MS Access) to create a directory using some date criteria in the name, but one of the variables I forgot to fill in, so it was only dimmed, not assigned anything.

But now I can't delete the folder because it tells me "Cannot read file: Cannot read from source or disk." How do I get rid of this?

For instance the folder name is "MyFolderName " (with the space). I was able to check the byte values of each character, and the last character has value 32 (space).

Comment: Search for folders which contain space at the end. Use Do - Loop and Dir function.

Comment: Have you tried building up the string the same way but instead of using MkDir you use RmDir?

Comment: @sous2817 Yes, it would say "file not found" when doing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was able to solve it by opening the command prompt and typing

```
rd "\\?\C:\path\to\bad\folder\badfoldername "
```

See Cause 5 in link https://support.microsoft.com/kb/320081